# Spring Boot 3.2 + Hibernate + LocalTime

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I'm using Spring Boot 3.2 with Hibernate 6.3.1.Final and I have the following entity

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class DummyEntity {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private LocalTime myTime;
}
```

Seems some values are not saved correctly. Here some examples

If I try to save LocalTime.MAX then the saved value will be "00:00"

If I try to save LocalTime.MAX.withNano(999_999_000) then the saved value will be "00:00"

If I try to save LocalTime.MAX.withNano(999_000_000) then the saved value is right.

Here an example of how I'm saving data

```
    var expectedMyTime = LocalTime.MAX;
    var nano = new DummyEntity();
    nano.setId(System.currentTimeMillis());
    String useCaseName = "nano";
    nano.setName(useCaseName);
    nano.setMyTime(expectedMyTime);
    dummyRepository.save(nano);
```

Where's my fault? Here the [github project](https://github.com/classicPintus/spring-boot-32-hibernate-date-time) that represents my current situation

Comment: I have added the following github project with specific tests that are failing. https://github.com/classicPintus/spring-boot-32-hibernate-date-time

Comment: this is a known issue with the version of hibernate you are using. just upgrade the hibernate version and test. please see my detailed response in the answers

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue of LocalTime.MAX rounding up to `00:00` in PostgreSQL when using Hibernate.

**Root Cause:**
Inconsistent Handling of Nanoseconds: Hibernate's internal representation of `LocalTime.MAX` (23:59:59.999999999) can conflict with PostgreSQL's TIME type, which stores nanoseconds with 6 digits of precision.
Truncation of Nanoseconds: When Hibernate persists LocalTime.MAX, PostgreSQL might truncate the last 3 nanosecond digits (999), effectively rounding up to the next day (00:00:00.000).

**Potential Solutions:**

1. Hibernate version `6.4.1.Final` and later addressed this issue with improved nanosecond handling. Upgrade if possible.
2. For earlier versions, set nanoseconds to 999,000,000 instead of 999,999,999 to avoid truncation

   ```java
    LocalTime adjustedMaxTime = LocalTime.of(23, 59, 59, 999_000_000);
   ```
3. Create a custom Hibernate type to handle full nanosecond precision for TIME values, bypassing PostgreSQL's limitations
4. Switch to TIMESTAMP. If feasible, consider using TIMESTAMP with higher precision for more accurate nanosecond storage

**Last Resort (may not be viable, but still can be considered):**

1. Explore alternative database systems with better nanosecond support for TIME types.
2. Adjust application logic to accommodate potential rounding if database storage of the exact LocalTime.MAX value isn't critical.